# Using exception for validate inputs

Tags: java, variables, exception

I'm new to programming & I tried to make an algorithm to find the grade of the marks entered by the user for each subject. At the beginning of the program user inputs all the marks for each subject. After that computer should automatically print all the subjects in the following order  `subject - mark - grade`.

I used the **do-while** loop for avoiding when the user inputs an out of range number. Also, I thought to use **try-catch** and **do-while** to avoid getting an invalid variable type from the user. I put the whole **try-catch** into another **do-while** loop. So, it has to be loop until the user inputs an integer value when an exception exists. But when I enter a wrong variable type like `A`  while the program is running, the computer decides that all the remaining inputs are invalid variables without the user's entry and prints the **"marks"** as zero and null for all those **"grades"** `>>Subject_4 - 0 - null`. Otherwise, if I input a correct variable it should print like this `>>Subject_1 - 56 - C`. How can I fix this? Please help me.

```
public class findResults {
int getMark;
int setMark;
String setGrade;
int arrayIndex;

String [] subjects = {"Subject_1","Subject_2","Subject_3","Subject_4"};
int [] marks = new int [subjects.length];
String[] grades = new String [subjects.length];

public findResults(){
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your marks for each subjects!");
    for (int t = 0;t<subjects.length;t++){
        arrayIndex = t;
        int x = 0;
    do{
        try {
            do{
                System.out.print(subjects[t]+" - ");
                getMark = scan.nextInt();
                setMark = ((getMark <= 100 && getMark >= 0)? getMark : (x=x-1));
                x = x+1;
            }while(x!=1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Please input valid number ..!");
    }
    }while(x!=x);
    
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<subjects.length;i++)
        System.out.println(subjects[i]+" - "+marks[i]+" - "+ grades[i]);
}
public void setResult(){
    if (setMark >= 75){
        setGrade = "A";
        marks[arrayIndex]= setMark;
        grades[arrayIndex]= setGrade;
    }
    else if(setMark >=65){
        setGrade = "A";
        marks[arrayIndex]= setMark;
        grades[arrayIndex]= setGrade;
    }
    else if(setMark >=65){
        setGrade = "B";
        marks[arrayIndex]= setMark;
        grades[arrayIndex]= setGrade;
    }
    else if(setMark >=55){
        setGrade = "C";
        marks[arrayIndex]= setMark;
        grades[arrayIndex]= setGrade;
    }
    else if(setMark >=35){
        setGrade = "S";
        marks[arrayIndex]= setMark;
        grades[arrayIndex]= setGrade;
    }
    else if(setMark >0){
        setGrade = "W";
        marks[arrayIndex]= setMark;
        grades[arrayIndex]= setGrade;
    }else{
        setGrade = "F";
        marks[arrayIndex]= setMark;
        grades[arrayIndex]= "Fail";
    }
}
    
}
```

Comment: `while(x!=x)` is **never** going to be true.

Comment: @Abra I tried ```while(x==1)``` . But, it's run extra loops even though I input a valid number. So, I tried this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```
private static String setGrade(int setMark) {
    String setGrade;
    if (setMark >= 75) {
        setGrade = "A";
    }
    else if (setMark >= 65) {
        setGrade = "B";
    }
    else if (setMark >= 55) {
        setGrade = "C";
    }
    else if (setMark >= 35) {
        setGrade = "S";
    }
    else if (setMark > 0) {
        setGrade = "W";
    }
    else {
        setGrade = "F";
    }
    return setGrade;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] subjects = {"Subject_1", "Subject_2", "Subject_3", "Subject_4"};
    int[] marks = new int[subjects.length];
    String[] grades = new String[subjects.length];
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your marks for each subject.");
    for (int t = 0; t < subjects.length; t++) {
        System.out.printf("%s - ", subjects[t]);
        try {
            String str = scan.nextLine();
            marks[t] = Integer.parseInt(str);
            if (marks[t] < 0 || marks[t] > 100) {
                System.out.println("Between 0 and 100, please. Re-enter.");
                t--;
                continue;
            }
            else {
                grades[t] = setGrade(marks[t]);
            }
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException xNumberFormat) {
            System.out.println("Invalid value. Re-enter.");
            t--;
            continue;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < subjects.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(subjects[i] + " - " + marks[i] + " - " + grades[i]);
    }
}
```

Below is the output from a sample run.

```
Enter your marks for each subject.
Subject_1 - -2
Between 0 and 100, please. Re-enter.
Subject_1 - a
Invalid value. Re-enter.
Subject_1 - 10
Subject_2 - 90
Subject_3 - 4.3
Invalid value. Re-enter.
Subject_3 - 43
Subject_4 - 007
Subject_1 - 10 - W
Subject_2 - 90 - A
Subject_3 - 43 - S
Subject_4 - 7 - W
```

Comment: Thank you @Abra. This is the output what I want ;)